# Executing optional (nullable) `Function` in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In some languages like Swift if you have Optional variable like below

```swift
var onItemPressed: ((Item) -> Void)?

// we can call this variable (function) like this
onItemPressed?(Item())
```

What's the equivalent of this in Dart language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent in Dart would be the `call` method on functions.

Like this,

```
onItemPressed?.call(Item())
```

So basically, whenever your `onItemPressed` is `null`, the execution short-circuits itself and it won't be called resulting in avoiding the crash.

Comment: `call` is not a keyword.